# Can Windows Phone 8.1 or 10 applications be created in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-2017

Can Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows Phone 10 applications be created in Visual Studio 2017?

Windows Phone 8.1 applications created in VS2015 are not loaded in VS2017.  Instead "(incompatible)" text is displayed in Solution Explorer (I get the same behavior for Windows 8.1 applications).

(This question is not about Xamarin projects)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VS2017 doesn't support Windows Phone 8.x or Windows 8.x applications, only UWP. Windows Phone 10 application you're asking about is actually UWP app for Windows 10 Mobile, so VS2017 can do that.

VS2015 supports both types, however you won't be able to target newer versions of SDK and .NET native toolchain for UWP.

Comment: Where do I find "UWP app for Windows 10 Mobile"? I only see "Visual C#/Windows Universal/ Blank app (Universal Windows)" - I assume that is Windows 10 Windows Store App, don't see Mobile version anywhere...It seems like I'm missing something from the installer.

Comment: There is no "for Windows 10 Mobile". UWP is Universal Windows Platform, an app created with UWP will work on any type of Windows 10. What you need to do, is to select "Windows Universal" blank app, and then you can deploy it to mobile or to desktop, or other platforms [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide).

Comment: Thanks. It seems that much has changed since 8.1 versions.

Comment: Projects for Windows Store 8.1 and 8.0, and Windows Phone 8.1 and 8.0 are not supported in this release. To maintain these apps, continue to use Visual Studio 2015. - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs The wording suggests that it might be supported in a future release.

Comment: I doubt that, they stopped supporting WP7 projects same way in VS2015

Answer (score 8):

From the doc.  Other "no support" elements are listed here as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects

> Windows Store/Phone apps - Projects for Windows Store 8.1 and 8.0, and
>   Windows Phone 8.1 and 8.0 are not supported in Visual Studio 2017. To
>   maintain these apps, continue to use Visual Studio 2015. To maintain
>   Windows Phone 7.x projects, use Visual Studio 2012.*

Answer (score 4):

From the [declined suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18433900-visual-studio-2017-add-support-for-windows-store) posted to UserVoice.

> Visual Studio 2015 continues to be a productive developer environment for maintaining Windows 8.1 Store apps. Visual Studio 2017 installs cleanly side by side with Visual Studio 2015, allowing you to maintain your existing Windows 8.1 Store apps in Visual Studio 2015, and to use the latest tools when it comes time to migrate your apps forward to Windows 10.